# CSS :after element relative position

Tags: css, css-position

I want to add an arrow effect to a list item (li) on it's hover but it's position does not act relative to list item. When I add left: 50% attiribute to :after element, every individual arrow become centered to ul instead of it's list item. Without left: 50% attiribute, arrows are under their list item's but not centered. So I'm a litte bit stucked here.

Here is my CSS:

```
nav.main-nav 
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 980px;
}
    nav.main-nav > ul > li
    {
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        list-style-type: none;            
        vertical-align: middle;
     }
     nav.main-nav > ul > li:hover
     {
         background-color: #304a60;
     }

          nav.main-nav > ul > li:hover:after
          {
                content: "";
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-left: 10px solid transparent;
                border-right: 10px solid transparent;
                border-top: 10px solid #304a60;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -10px;
                left: 50%;
           }
```

Any help will be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: Div's with position:absolute can't find his parent with  display: table-cell. Remove this css or add new parent

Comment: The left side of the triangle looks centered to me, just move it 10px left to center it... or am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/FyUU8/2/  (also, firefox bugs with the table-cell display, changed to inline)

Comment: @xec's fiddle looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the arrow on the `a` itself, which you can set to `display: block` and `position: relative`. Then you have your positioning context for `a:after`.